# How to dynamically load a .dat icon (toolshelf icon)?

Tags: python, add-on

Using documentation here [2.80/Python_API/UI_DESIGN](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/UI_DESIGN), I've managed to create a custom .dat tool shelf icon for use with an operator in my addon. The icon will display from my addon when registered from a class like this if the .dat icon file has been previously pasted directly into the active Blender installation datafiles directory (.../2.92/datafiles/icons/my_addon.operator_icon.dat):

```
class MYADDON_some_tool(WorkSpaceTool):
    bl_idname = "my_addon.some_operator"
    bl_label = "My Operator"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_context_mode = 'OBJECT'
    bl_icon = 'my_addon.operator_icon'
```

As far as I can tell, this will not work if simply including "icons/my_addon.operator_icon.dat" or "datafiles/icons/my_addon.operator_icon.dat" within an addon, nor any other area of a user settings directory as can be done with contents within the scripts and config directories. Is there some location within a user settings folder (or even better an addon directory) that Blender will detect an icons directory from? If not, is there some way to dynamically load a .dat icon file within an addon? Strangely, the doc I linked to is, in general, talking about addons in Blender 2.8. But there doesn't appear to be a way to load a .dat icon file from an addon without pasting into the core instillation of Blender.

Comment: Turns out the datafiles directory is accessible via user settings directory. Shows up in user settings when installing an HDR via preferences > lights menu (for example). Blender doesn't appear to run a sweep for contents of icons folder within the datafiles directory from user settings directory as with the core install directory though.